# Best design for processing message in asynchronous socket client

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I am trying to write an asynchronous socket client where it has a continuos feed from the server.
The client needs to get the data, and then display it on the GUI. It also needs a way for processing user messages, such as button clicks.

What is the best way to implement this?

1. Use timer and call reading function when the timer event fires?
2. Use while(true) loop to read the data and just yield somewhere in reading function to allow message processing? However I don't think I have control on the reading thread process in C#.
3. Something else?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it assumed that this is a web-based application you're designing, or do we assume a generic platform?

Comment: @DavidHoerster, yes it is a web based client/server app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a good tool to consider is [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR), which allows async communication between clients and servers (not just web-based clients).

Comment: David, it needs to be generic C#.NET application.

Comment: Using a 3rd party library isn't allowed?  If so, I'll delete this.

Comment: it just needs to be built with as few dependancies as possible. the thing is its a transition fron borland c++ to .NET and the original was built with 3rd party GUI library which makes it ugly to work with. so now the less deps the better.

Comment: the original program uses timer to do the processing, but I was thinking that C# being designed specifically for internet client-server communication have some other means to do just that.